# Conditionally replace a value in one column through similarity of two rows in another column

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

my dataframe looks like this:

```
   Country   Type  Origin Transfer Weight Price
1  Belgium Export   Mixed  Armenia    234     5
2  Armenia Import Belgium  Belgium    234     6
3   Israel Export   Mixed  Armenia    457     8
4  Armenia Import   Mixed   Israel    457     8
5 Botswana Import  Angola   Angola   2510    30
6   Angola Export  Angola Botswana   2510    35
```

I want it to look like this (only 1 change: Mixed became Belgium):

```
   Country   Type  Origin Transfer Weight Price
1  Belgium Export Belgium  Armenia    234     5
2  Armenia Import Belgium  Belgium    234     6
3   Israel Export   Mixed  Armenia    457     8
4  Armenia Import   Mixed   Israel    457     8
5 Botswana Import  Angola   Angola   2510    30
6   Angola Export  Angola Botswana   2510    35
```

code:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Country = c("Belgium", "Armenia", "Israel", "Armenia", "Botswana", "Angola"),   
  Type = c("Export", "Import", "Export", "Import", "Import", "Export"),
  Origin = c("Mixed", "Belgium", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Angola", "Angola"),   
  Transfer = c("Armenia", "Belgium", "Armenia", "Israel", "Angola", "Botswana"),  
  Weight = c(234, 234, 457, 457, 2510, 2510),   
  Price = c(5, 6, 8, 8, 30, 35)
)
```

So I would like to write a function that, if `Origin == "Mixed"`, it gets the value of Origin of the row that has an identical value for Weight.
Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

We can `arrange` the rows by 'Weight' and a logical expression created with 'Origin', grouped by 'Weight', `mutate` to change the 'Origin' as the `first` element, `ungroup`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  arrange(Weight, Origin == 'Mixed') %>%
  group_by(Weight) %>% 
  mutate(Origin = first(Origin)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(rn) %>%
  select(-rn)
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 6 x 6
#  Country  Type   Origin  Transfer Weight Price
#  <chr>    <chr>  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Belgium  Export Belgium Armenia     234     5
#2 Armenia  Import Belgium Belgium     234     6
#3 Israel   Export Mixed   Armenia     457     8
#4 Armenia  Import Mixed   Israel      457     8
#5 Botswana Import Angola  Angola     2510    30
#6 Angola   Export Angola  Botswana   2510    35
```

Comment: This works well. Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `ave`

```
transform(
  df,
  Origin = ave(Origin,
    Weight,
    FUN = function(x) {
      ifelse(mean(x == "Mixed") == 1,
        "Mixed",
        x[x != "Mixed"]
      )
    }
  )
)
```

gives

```
   Country   Type  Origin Transfer Weight Price
1  Belgium Export Belgium  Armenia    234     5
2  Armenia Import Belgium  Belgium    234     6
3   Israel Export   Mixed  Armenia    457     8
4  Armenia Import   Mixed   Israel    457     8
5 Botswana Import  Angola   Angola   2510    30
6   Angola Export  Angola Botswana   2510    35
```

Comment: It's probably my fault or a result of the dataset structure, but this method didn't work; it turned all Origin values that weren't "Mixed" to NAs. But thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a helper function -

```
library(dplyr)

replace_mixed <- function(Origin) {
  val <- Origin[Origin != 'Mixed'][1]
  if(is.na(val)) Origin else val
}

df %>%
  group_by(Weight) %>%
  mutate(Origin = replace_mixed(Origin)) %>%
  ungroup

#  Country  Type   Origin  Transfer Weight Price
#  <chr>    <chr>  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Belgium  Export Belgium Armenia     234     5
#2 Armenia  Import Belgium Belgium     234     6
#3 Israel   Export Mixed   Armenia     457     8
#4 Armenia  Import Mixed   Israel      457     8
#5 Botswana Import Angola  Angola     2510    30
#6 Angola   Export Angola  Botswana   2510    35
```

Comment: This works well. Thank you for your quick response.